# What's the most efficient method to align tiles?

Tags: game-maker

I've got 17 tiles that need to have the image they draw changed based on the surrounding blocks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFsIw.png

I could do this, but it's extremely cumbersome and bug prone, I wasn't able to get it to work.

```
if left != mine and right = mine and top = mine and bottom != mine {tile_indexID[ww,hh] = 0;} // 
if left = mine and right != mine and top = mine and bottom != mine {tile_indexID[ww,hh] = 1;} //
if left != mine and right = mine and top = !mine and bottom = mine {tile_indexID[ww,hh] = 2;} // 
if left != mine and right = mine and top = mine and bottom != mine {tile_indexID[ww,hh] = 3;} //
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What I used when aligning sprite as you are

is that for objects

```
if (place_meeting(x,y-16,obj_tile)) { 
    image_index = top;
}
```

This what i used but the code of IF statements and nested IF statements get very long in code number but it *can* be easier to debug if you put nice commenting in.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this;
http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=416796

Answer (score 0):

Use bitmasking.
Good description from `angry fish studios` site.

[image]